# float number and usleep problem

Tags: c, usleep

Im wrinting app which has that piece of code, where t->tick is float:

```
usleep(1000);
t->tick = t->tick + 0.001;
printf("tick is %f, firing time is %f\n", t->tick, t->firing_time);
```

i found that there is error in usleep?:

```
tick is 0.313000, firing time is 2.000000
tick is 0.314000, firing time is 2.000000
tick is 0.314999, firing time is 2.000000
tick is 0.315999, firing time is 2.000000
```

How to get rid of that error ?

Comment: How is `firing_time` calculated?

Comment: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: Then what's the error? Are you referring to the .000999 in `t->tick`?

Comment: yes, that's what im talking about

Answer (score 2):

There's no error, you simply do not understand how binary floating-point math works.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a rounding stability error in printf.

Try: printf("tick is %.3f, firing time is %.3f\n", t->tick, t->firing_time);

Comment: nope, cause when im testing condition firing_time==tick, i always got false

Comment: @josip You can't compare floating point numbers like that. The usual approach is to subtract the two floats, and check to see if the result is smaller than a given value, like 0.001.

Comment: Where do you see a comparison operation here?

Comment: This is not `printf`'s doing, it is fundamental to floating point arithmetic. There is no perfectly accurate representation for 0.001, so there can not be perfectly accurate mathematics involving that quantity.